# Strange results when deleting all special characters from a string in Progress / OpenEdge

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have the code snippet below (as suggested in this previous Stack Overflow answer ... [Deleting all special characters from a string in progress 4GL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525858/deleting-all-special-characters-from-a-string-in-progress-4gl)) which is attempting to remove all extended characters from a string so that I may transmit it to a customer's system which will not accept any extended characters.

> do v-int = 128 to 255:
>
> ```
>   assign v-string = replace(v-string,chr(v-int),"").
> ```
>
> end.

It is working perfectly with one exception (which makes me fear there may be others I have not caught).  When it gets to 255, it will replace all 'y's in the string.

If I do the following ...

> display chr(255) = chr(121).   /* 121 is asc code of y */

I get true as the result.

And therefore, if I do the following ...

> display replace("This is really strange",chr(255),"").

I get the following result:

> This is reall strange

I have verified that 'y' is the only character affected by running the following:

> def var v-string as char init "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
>   def var v-int as int.
>
> do v-int = 128 to 255:
>
> assign v-string = replace(v-string,chr(v-int),"").
>
> end.
>
> display v-string.

Which results in the following:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz

I know I can fix this by removing 255 from the range but I would like to understand why this is happening.

Is this a character collation set issue or am I missing something simpler?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug!

> The REPLACE() function returns an unexpected result when replacing character CHR(255) (ÿ)  in a String.
>
> The REPLACE() function modifies the value of the target character, but additionally it changes any occurrence of characters  'Y' and 'y' present in the String.
>
> This behavior seems to affect only the character ÿ. Other characters are correctly changed by REPLACE().
>
> Using default codepage ISO-8859-1

[Link to knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/REPLACEfunctionreturnswrongresultforcharacteryumlaut)

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I tried to do an upvote but since I am a new registrant it wouldn't let me.  :(

Comment: I will add a reminder to my calendar to check back in a few weeks when I have enough reputation points to do upvotes and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug. Here's a Progress Knowledge Base article about it:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000046181

The workaround is to specify the codepage in the `CHR()` statement, like this:

```
CHR(255, "UTF-8", "1252")
```

Here it is in your example:

```
def var v-string as char init "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". def var v-int as int.

do v-int = 128 to 255:

assign v-string = replace(v-string, chr(v-int, "UTF-8", "1252"), "").

end.

display v-string.
```

You should now see the 'y' in the output.

Comment: The bug looks like a simple error in the convmap file (%DLC%/prolang/convmap/8859-1.dat), the uppercase-maps entry for ÿ (255) is 089 which is a /normal/ Y.

That information also leads you to an alternative solution - make sure one of the two variables is case-sensitive.